# Client-Certificate based Authentication with HttpComponents

Tags: java, apache, ssl, certificate, socketexception

i'm facing a problem concerning a certificate based authentication by using apaches httpcomponents. Everytime i start the request i get the response code 403. If i turn of the ssl encryption and the authentication the connection can be established successfully.

I'm assuming that the certificates are okay, because they already worked in a different context.

The following code shows how i start the request.

```
HttpClient httpClient = null;
try
{

    HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();

    KeyStore rootca = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
    rootca.load(new FileInputStream("server.jks"), "bara".toCharArray());

    KeyStore mycert = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
    mycert.load(new FileInputStream("client.jks"), "bara".toCharArray());

    SSLSocketFactory sockfact = new SSLSocketFactory(mycert, "bara", rootca);
    sockfact.setHostnameVerifier(SSLSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER); 
    SchemeRegistry registry = new SchemeRegistry();
    registry.register(new Scheme("http", PlainSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(), 80));
    registry.register(new Scheme("https", sockfact, 443));
    httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(new ThreadSafeClientConnManager(httpParameters, registry), httpParameters);

    HttpGet get = new HttpGet("https://mycomputer.mynetwork/test");
    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(get);

    System.out.println(response.getStatusLine());

}
```

There is no exception or futher message. I debugged the code by downloading the sources. Even then i cannot localize the error. Merely the following exception is thrown but i cannot see the reason. "Connection reset by peer: socket write error"

I would be thankful for every idea.

Kind regards.

Update: after editing the logging preferences i get the following exception:

```
reset by peer: socket write error>javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Connection has been shutdown: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.checkEOF(SSLSocketImpl.java:1325)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.checkWrite(SSLSocketImpl.java:1337)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(AppOutputStream.java:44)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionOutputBuffer.flushBuffer(AbstractSessionOutputBuffer.java:131)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionOutputBuffer.flush(AbstractSessionOutputBuffer.java:138)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.LoggingSessionOutputBuffer.flush(LoggingSessionOutputBuffer.java:95)
    at org.apache.http.impl.AbstractHttpClientConnection.doFlush(AbstractHttpClientConnection.java:271)
    at org.apache.http.impl.SocketHttpClientConnection.close(SocketHttpClientConnection.java:246)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection.close(DefaultClientConnection.java:164)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.close(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:152)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.closeConnection(HttpRequestExecutor.java:142)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:129)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryExecute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:647)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:464)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:820)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:754)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:732)
    at Client.main(Client.java:54)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:190)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1731)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1692)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.handleException(SSLSocketImpl.java:1656)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.handleException(SSLSocketImpl.java:1601)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(AppOutputStream.java:93)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionOutputBuffer.flushBuffer(AbstractSessionOutputBuffer.java:131)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionOutputBuffer.flush(AbstractSessionOutputBuffer.java:138)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.LoggingSessionOutputBuffer.flush(LoggingSessionOutputBuffer.java:95)
    at org.apache.http.impl.AbstractHttpClientConnection.doFlush(AbstractHttpClientConnection.java:271)
    at org.apache.http.impl.AbstractHttpClientConnection.flush(AbstractHttpClientConnection.java:276)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractClientConnAdapter.flush(AbstractClientConnAdapter.java:194)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doSendRequest(HttpRequestExecutor.java:258)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:123)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:92)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:136)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.OutputRecord.writeBuffer(OutputRecord.java:297)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.OutputRecord.write(OutputRecord.java:286)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecordInternal(SSLSocketImpl.java:748)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:736)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(AppOutputStream.java:88)
    ... 14 more
```

Answer (score 0):

In the context of SSL/TLS a connection closed by the server means that something went wrong in the connection handshake phase. May be the client certificate was not accepted or the available cipher suites of client and server were incompatible.

For finding out what is going wrong you have to look into the network traffic, e.g. using Wireshark. It allows you to look into every packet sent.

Additionally I would test the certificates using OpenSSL using the [s_client](http://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/s_client.html) mode - just to make sure it is not a general problem with your client certificate.

Comment: thanks for your response. Unfortunately i'm pretty new to openssl. Could u give an example how i can validate my certs?

Comment: OpenSSL can not work with JKS keystores, therefore you have to extract the server/root certificate, the client certificate and the client key to a file. Afterwards you can execute `openssl s_client -connect mycomputer.mynetwork:443 -cert client.cer -certform DER -key client.key -CAfile root.cer`

Comment: Okay, i've tried it.. it says return code "0" so that certs should be okay

Comment: Stil getting the same error. Already tried to validate the certs. They seem to be okay. Network traffic is a bit strange. I cannot see the transfer of the client cert. I remember earlier i saw the servers request to provide a client certificate. But the client cert is transferred. I can see it within my server application. Does anybody has further suggestions?